# Get the start and end dates visible in a datepicker days view?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [bootstrap datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#)

I wanna get the first and the last dates in the calendar.

[image]

How can I get those dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no any in-built option/method to get the dates what you have asked. But the following approach gives you those dates.

**Approach** : Get the current month, subtract it by the number of `.old` days to get the starting date or add the number of `.new` days to get the end date.

It works even if the `weekStart` is option is changed.

```js
var startdate = document.getElementById("startdate");
var enddate = document.getElementById("enddate");

$("#date").datepicker('update', new Date()).on("show",function(date){
    var date = new Date($(this).data("datepicker").getDate());
    var startofmonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(),1);
    var endofmonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0);
    startofmonth.setDate(startofmonth.getDate()-$(".datepicker .old.day").length);
    endofmonth.setDate(endofmonth.getDate()+$(".datepicker .new.day").length);
    startdate.textContent = "Start : "+startofmonth;
    enddate.textContent = "End : "+endofmonth;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css"/>

<span id="startdate">Start : </span><br>
<span id="enddate">End : </span><br>
<input id="date">
```

**Note**: If you are using other locales instead of `en`, then replace the first line in the `show` method by the following lines.

```
var language = $("#date").data("datepicker").o.language;
var months = $.fn.datepicker.dates[language].months;
var view = document.querySelector(".datepicker-days .datepicker-switch").textContent.split(" ");
var date = new Date(view[1],months.indexOf(view[0]),1);
```

**Update on Why addition/subtraction by dayOfWeek to start/end dates shouldn't be used to get the result (Must read):**

1. The datepicker always has 7 columns(as intended) and 6 rows(constant). For instance, take the month *May, 2019*, it has 31 days and need only 5 rows in the calendar, but 6 rows are displayed, including the next month's dates. Here the addition/subtraction won't work.
2. If `weekStart` is changed, `weekStart` must be taken into consideration while addition/subtraction by day.

Comment: Checked again. Its working for me. Can you please give more info about the browser u checked with

Comment: Ok I got it, Its working in chrome but not working in Firefox 67.0.3 ubuntu

Comment: @AabirHussain Thanks for notify me. The issue is because, Firefox and Safari supports only ISO date formats, where Chrome analyzes the date and finds the format (if it is not in ISO). 'Month Year' format is not supported in FF and Safari. Updated the code to work in cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
In the action "show" I put this code.

```
(e) => {
    let date = e.date;    
    date.setUTCFullYear(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    let weekDay = date.getDay();    

    let daysAgo;
    if (weekDay == 1) {
        daysAgo = 8;
    } else if (weekDay == 0) {
        daysAgo = 7;
    } else {
        daysAgo = weekDay;
    }

    let begin = new Date(date.getTime() - daysAgo * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    let end   = new Date(begin.getTime() + 43 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

Now in the variable begin and end we have those dates accordingly.