# Get the first and last visible date of the fullcalendar without using datepicker

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I use fullcalendar in my code and have implemented and added events into it, but my goal was to get the first visible and last visible date of the calendar.

What we wanted to do is get the visible first and last dates so that we'll be able to throw the extracted dates in the database and get all events within that range of dates.

I've tried this [Get the start and end dates visible in a datepicker days view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233624/get-the-start-and-end-dates-visible-in-a-datepicker-days-view) but I want to use jQuery and fullCalendar only. Is there other way to extract the dates without using datepicker?

[image]

Comment: According to the SO [fullcalendar] tag, the versions are very different so you need to include the verison of fullcalendar

Comment: hi @freedomn-m, thank you for your response. So what we wanted to do is get the visible first and last dates so that we'll be able to throw the extracted dates in the database and get all events within that range of dates.

Comment: Is it possible to get the first date of the first week and last date of the last week of the fullcalendar? because I'm not sure if this possible because I've researched on my part but  only can get the current week's first and last dates.

Comment: Looks like it's always 6 weeks from from the Monday from on or before the first of the month.   So you could get dates as:  [first date] = [first of month] - [day of week of first of month]  and [last date] = [first date] + (6*7)days

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, I think I'm almost there. This is a great help~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using version 5.5.1, you can inspect the *rendered* HTML.  The day cells have class `fc-daygrid-day` and `data-date="{date}"`

Given the original div id is "calendar" you can use:

```
var cells = $("#calendar td.fc-daygrid-day");
console.log(cells.length, cells.first().data("date"), cells.last().data("date"))
```

Example snippet:

```js
$(function() { 
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  });
  calendar.render();
  
  var cells = $("#calendar td.fc-daygrid-day");
  console.log(cells.length, cells.first().data("date"), cells.last().data("date"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.css">

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: True but it's an unnecessary workaround. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object

Comment: @ADyson yes, it was a work around for the OP not knowing how to use the API

Comment: Sure but then maybe tell them about the API instead? See my answer.

Comment: @freedomn-m, this works well for me even if I am not using the v5 fullcalendar.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but could you tell us which version/options you *are* using - ideally with a small snippet in the question.  Then we (probably @ADyson ...) can provide you with updated details on the correct way.  This should only be a temporary "hack". :)

Comment: @freedomn-m, so I just added this one in my code

  var cells = $("#calendar td.fc-daygrid-day");
  console.log(cells.length, cells.first().data("date"), cells.last().data("date"))

 and it gives me the dates i was looking for. Cuirrently using the v2

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get the first date of the first week and last date
> of the last week of the fullcalendar

...yes easily - in the latest version (v5 at the time of writing) you can just ask for the [current view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/Calendar-view) and it [has properties which contain those dates](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/view-object).

However, you also said this was

> so that we'll be able to throw the extracted dates in the database and
> get all events within that range of dates.

There's no reason for you to do this manually, if that's your purpose. FullCalendar already provides ways of specifying the source of your events - you can either simply [point it at a URL](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) which returns JSON in the fullCalendar events format, or if you need more flexibility, you can [define a callback function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) where you can use custom code to fetch the events from their source.

The key thing about both those approaches is that fullcalendar automatically

- calls the URL / runs the function every time the date range changes on the calendar, and
- provides you with the start and end dates of the new date range, so that your server can filter the events it returns to be only ones which fall within that range.

There's no need for you to spend time manually attempting to extract date ranges from the calendar or feed it events by other methods.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson as well for explaining, this will help me in the future!!

Comment: @Jane Is there any particular reason why it doesn't help you right now as well?

Comment: some of it helps actually since v5 is almost the same with v2.  I am currently using fullcalendar v2.

Comment: Oh ok, that's a very old version. Any reason you still use that? v5 has many more features, bug fixes etc. P.S. You can tag your question with the version, because the versions often have some different features.

Comment: Anyway yes [events as JSON](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed) and (events as function)[https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function] which I mentioned above both exist in v2, although the syntax you use is slightly different, but the idea and the basic behaviour is the same. And to take the more basic approach of getting the view, you'd use [getView](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/getView). (note that link says v3 but as the documentation says, v3 and v2 have the same outward-facing API so the documentation is identical.)

Comment: Actually, I am not the first person who started the program so, it's a lot of work to do when I have to revise it again to v5. That's why I have adapted what the prior person did. And that's true, the syntax is slightly different, that is, maybe I haven't found the right answer but now. In the near future, if I will have to create another calendar for another program I will surely apply what you've answered in this question. Anyway, thank you very much I really gained knowledge. This is a big help! Kudos! :)